# curl json source empty page

Tags: php, json, curl

I get error reading data from json source, I get a blank page error.

I am making a mistake.

I just want to get the category BetTypeId = 3.

Could you help?

```
 <?php
error_reporting(1);
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.misli.com/scripts/BetList.aspx?action=get&BetTypeId&3",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  //CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
  ),
));
$ok = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo "<Maclar>";

                if($ok->BetTypeId=="3")
                {
                $tarih = $ok->CloseDate;
                $ulke = $ok->CountryName;
                echo '<ulke="'.$ulke.'" tarih="'.$tarih.'" />'; 
                }
    echo "</Maclar>";
}
?>
```

Comment: the base item is an array try `$ok[0]->BetTypeId` or start using `foreach($ok as $object){echo $object->BetTypeId;}`

Comment: empty :( https://i.hizliresim.com/OyQpzP.jpg

Comment: Oh, you didn't `$ok = curl_exec($curl); $ok = json_decode($ok);`

Comment: it turns into a blank page again, yes I am making a mistake but I can not find the cause of the error.

Comment: Try this if you keep getting a blank page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\4\o5t\misli\yeni.php on line 29...  [ foreach($ok as $object){]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target site you want to fetch data will check the browser agent.

Add the agent and fix the problem pointed out by Scuzzy, then your code will work.

You could refer the following code. Please note there may be error of your xml format, that will cause the browser doesn't display the response data normally. But I did get the response `<Maclar><ulke="Şampiyonlar Ligi" tarih="2018-02-13T22:45:00" /></Maclar>`

The code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.misli.com/scripts/BetList.aspx?action=get&BetTypeId&3",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$agent,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => "accept: application/json"
));

$ok = curl_exec($curl);
//echo $ok;
$ok = json_decode($ok);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} 
else {
    echo "<Maclar>";

    if($ok[0]->BetTypeId=="3")
    {
        $tarih = $ok[0]->CloseDate;
        $ulke = $ok[0]->CountryName;
        echo '<ulke="'.$ulke.'" tarih="'.$tarih.'" />'; 
    }
    echo "</Maclar>";
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest, Phil. again a blank page comes up :( I can not figure out where I'm making the mistake ...

Comment: You could check the source code of your page. The response data are right there. As I mentioned, your xml formt may be not good, so it won't display the result in browser.

Comment: Thank you very much, Phil.
I have a very small problem right now, in the json array source "." var and <b> Parse error </ b>: syntax error, unexpected '.1' (T_DNUMBER).

$ ev = $ cok-> bets-> F.1-> OV; (Point after F)

Comment: Did you use exactly the same code? I just check and the code remains working fine. If you changed some code, please post it here and let us check.